# contains_eager and limits in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have 2 classes:

```
class A(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    children = relationship('B')
class B(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    id_a = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('a.id'))
    name = Column(String)
```

Now I need all object A which contains B with some name and A object will contain all B objects filtered.

To achieve it I build query.

```
query = db.session.query(A).join(B).options(db.contains_eager(A.children)).filter(B.name=='SOME_TEXT')
```

Now I need only 50 items of query so I do:

```
query.limit(50).all()
```

Result contain less then 50 even if without limit there is more than 50. I read The Zen of Eager Loading. But there must be some trick to achieve it. One of my idea is to make 2 query. One with innerjoin to take ID's then use this ID's in first query.

But maybe there is better solve for this.

Answer (score 4):

First, take a step back and look at the SQL. Your current query is

```
SELECT * FROM a JOIN b ON b.id_a = a.id WHERE b.name == '...' LIMIT 50;
```

Notice the limit is on `a JOIN b` and not `a`, but if you put the limit on `a` you can't filter by the field in `b`. There are two solutions to this problem. The first is to use a scalar subquery to filter on `b.name`, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM b WHERE b.id_a = a.id AND b.name = '...')
LIMIT 50;
```

This can be inefficient depending on the DB backend. The second solution is to do a DISTINCT on `a` after the join, like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.* FROM a JOIN b ON b.id_a = a.id
WHERE b.name == '...'
LIMIT 50;
```

Notice how in either case you do not get any column from `b`. How do we get them? Do another join!

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT a.* FROM a JOIN b ON b.id_a = a.id
    WHERE b.name == '...'
    LIMIT 50;
) a JOIN b ON b.id_a = a.id
WHERE b.name == '...';
```

Now, to write all of this in SQLAlchemy:

```
subquery = (
    session.query(A)
           .join(B)
           .with_entities(A)  # only select A's columns
           .filter(B.name == '...')
           .distinct()
           .limit(50)
           .subquery()  # convert to subquery
)
aliased_A = aliased(A, subquery)
query = (
    session.query(aliased_A)
           .join(B)
           .options(contains_eager(aliased_A.children))
           .filter(B.name == "...")
)
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what DB backends would suffer from using EXISTS (possibly planned as a semijoin), for example.

Comment: @IljaEverilä It's one of those things that depend heavily on multiple factors, like database engine, version, and query, so it's difficult to give a straight answer. *In a general sense*, joins are *usually* more efficient than subqueries. As always, profile to figure it out.

Comment: That's just the thing, as EXISTS can be and is implemented as a semijoin, at least in some dbs. Of course that might not apply to all queries, but usually happens in this kind of simple case. But in the end I guess you're right on the money: profile and see.