# contains_eager on noload relationship works starange

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

**DB**

```
mysql> select * from comment;
+----+--------+---------+
| id | body   | post_id |
+----+--------+---------+
|  1 | first  |       1 |
|  2 | second |       1 |
|  3 | third  |       1 |
+----+--------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from post;
+----+-------+
| id | title |
+----+-------+
|  1 | abc   |
+----+-------+
```

**Models**

```
class Comment(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'comment'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    body = Column(Unicode(255))
    post_id = Column(ForeignKey('post.id'))


class Post(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'post'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    title = Column(Unicode(255), nullable=False)

    comments = relationship('Comment', lazy='noload')
```

Querying to relationship `comments` that belong to `Post`.

```
post = session.query(Post).join(
    Comment,
    Comment.post_id == Post.id,
).options(
    contains_eager(Post.comments)
).first()
print(post.comments)
print(post.comments[0].__dict__)
```

**Result**

```
[<models.Comment object at 0x10fa70eb0>]
{'_sa_instance_state': <sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState object at 0x10d151ee0>, 'id': 1, 'post_id': 1, 'body': 'first'}
```

As you know that I added `lazy='noload'` option to comments relationship.

However, it has nothing to do with the contains_eager option.

But query result return only first comments.

Why it does not return all of comments related on post_id = 1?

Thanks.

Comment: There's one thing missing from your example: how do you perform the query? Do you use `first()`? I'm somewhat sure that your issue is not so much about the interplay of noload and contains eager, but contains eager and limits: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41900315/contains-eager-and-limits-in-sqlalchemy

Comment: @Ilja Everilä I used first()

Comment: There's your culprit then. If you inspect the query emitted to the DB, you'll notice `LIMIT 1` or equivalent being sent. One way around it is to use `all()` instead and extract the first entity from the resulting list.